# Bulk download in Aura lightning component

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I am looking for bulk download functionality but not able to do it, please help me. I am trying to download records, if I select all the records from checkboxes.

Here I am using handleMassDownload for downloading records in below. I need to download all the files from table in zip format. Please help me out on above problem statment.
Here is my code:

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered" aria-label="Example default base table of Opportunities">
<thead>
<tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
<th class="" scope="col">
<!---->
<lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="headerCheckbox" checked="{!v.isHeaderChecked}" name="headerCheckbox" onchange="{!c.headerCheckHandler}"/>
</th>

<th class="" scope="col">
<div class="slds-truncate" title="Decision">Decision</div>
</th>
<th class="" scope="col">
<div class="slds-truncate" title="Title">Title</div>
</th>
<th class="" scope="col">
<div class="slds-truncate" title="Type">Type</div>
</th>
<th class="" scope="col">
<div class="slds-truncate" title="Upload Date">Upload Date</div>
</th>

<th class="" scope="col">
<div class="slds-truncate" title="Owner">Owner</div>
</th>
<th class="" scope="col">
<div class="slds-truncate" title="Actions">Actions</div>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.documentList}" var="doc" indexVar="indx">
<tr  class="slds-hint-parent">
<td  class="slds-truncate">
<lightning:input type="checkbox" name="{!indx}" value="{!doc.Id}" aura:id="inputCheckbox" onchange="{!c.handleCheckboxChange}"/>
</td>
<td  class="slds-truncate">
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:success" size="small" />
<aura:set attribute="else">
<aura:if isTrue="{!doc.Decision__c == 'Rejected'}">
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:error" size="small" />
<aura:set attribute="else">
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:warning" size="small" />
</aura:set>
</aura:if>
</aura:set>
</aura:if>-->
</td>
<td  class="slds-truncate">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.navigateToAppPage}" data-record-id="{!doc.Id}">{!doc.Name}</a>
</td>
<td  class="slds-truncate">{!doc.DocumentType__c}</td>
<td  class="slds-truncate">{!doc.Upload_Date__c}</td>
<td  class="slds-truncate">{!doc.Owner.Name}</td>
<td  class="slds-truncate" >
<lightning:button label="Delete" iconName="utility:delete" onclick="{!c.handleDelete}" variant="destructive" value="{!doc.Id}" />
<lightning:button label="Download" iconName="utility:download" onclick="{!c.handleDownload}" value="{!doc.Id}" />
</td>
</tr>
</aura:iteration>
</tbody>
</table>
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.refreshDocumentList(component);
    },
    
    
    handleMassDownload : function(component, event, helper){
         let navService = component.find( "navService");
        let documentList = component.get('v.documentList');
        let docId = event.getSource().get('v.value');
        console.log('docId: ' + docId);
        
        let cvId = '';
        console.log('documentList: ', documentList); 
        
        documentList.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log('item.Id: ', item.Id);             
            if (item.Id == docId) {
                
                console.log('IF Match found!');
                cvId = item.ContentVersionId__c;
            }
        });
        
        console.log('cvId: ' + cvId);
        let filesDownloadUrl = '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/' + cvId;
        console.log('filesDownloadUrl : ' + filesDownloadUrl);
        let pageReference = {
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: filesDownloadUrl
            }
        };
        navService.navigate(
            pageReference
        );
    },
    headerCheckHandler: function(component, event, helper) {
        var headerCheckbox = component.find("headerCheckbox");
        var checkboxes = component.find("inputCheckbox");
        
        if (!Array.isArray(checkboxes)) {
            checkboxes.set('v.checked', headerCheckbox.get('v.checked'));
        } else {
            checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
                checkbox.set('v.checked', headerCheckbox.get('v.checked'));
            });
        }
    },
    
    handleCheckboxChange: function(component, event, helper){
        let selectedDocId = [];
        let count = 0;
       // let name = event.getSource().get('v.name');
        let findAllInput = component.find('inputCheckbox');
        component.set('v.isHeaderChecked',false);
        console.log('findAllInput : ' + findAllInput.length);
        //console.log('name : ' + name);
        //let isChecked = findAllInput[name].get('v.checked');
        
        for(let i=0; i<findAllInput.length; i++){
            let isChecked = findAllInput[i].get('v.checked');
            if(isChecked){
                count++;
                selectedDocId.push(findAllInput[i].get('v.value'));
            }
        }
            /*if(count == findAllInput.length){
                component.set('v.isHeaderChecked',true);
            } else {
                component.set('v.isHeaderChecked',false);
            }*/
        component.set('v.isHeaderChecked', count === findAllInput.length);
        component.set('v.selectedDocId', selectedDocId);
        
        console.log('selectedDocId : ' + selectedDocId);
    },
    
    handleDownload: function(component, event, helper) {
        let navService = component.find( "navService");
        let documentList = component.get('v.documentList');
        let docId = event.getSource().get('v.value');
        console.log('docId: ' + docId);
        
        let cvId = '';
        console.log('documentList: ', documentList); 
        
        documentList.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log('item.Id: ', item.Id);             
            if (item.Id == docId) {
                
                console.log('IF Match found!');
                cvId = item.ContentVersionId__c;
            }
        });
        
        console.log('cvId: ' + cvId);
        let filesDownloadUrl = '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/' + cvId;
        console.log('filesDownloadUrl : ' + filesDownloadUrl);
        let pageReference = {
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: filesDownloadUrl
            }
        };
        navService.navigate(
            pageReference
        );
    },
    
    handleFileChange: function(component, event, helper) {
         component.set('v.isLoading',true);
        let selectedFiles = component.find("fileId").get("v.files");
        let selectedFile = selectedFiles[ 0 ];
        console.log('File Name is',selectedFile.name);
        component.set("v.fileName",selectedFile.name);
        console.log('File Size is',selectedFile.size);
        let objFileReader = new FileReader();    
        objFileReader.onload = $A.getCallback( function() {
            let fileContent = objFileReader.result;
            let base64 = 'base64,';
            let dataStart = fileContent.indexOf( base64 ) + base64.length; 
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( dataStart );
            helper.processFileUpload( component, fileContent, selectedFile );
        } ); 
        objFileReader.readAsDataURL(
            selectedFile 
        );
        //helper.uploadFiles(component, files);
    },
    navigateToAppPage: function(component, event, helper) {
        //alert('navigateToAppPage');
         // Get the record Id from the data-record-id attribute
        var recordId = event.currentTarget.dataset.recordId;
        //alert('recordId'+recordId);

        // Use the navigation service to navigate to the app page
        var navService = component.find("navService");

        var pageReference = {
            type: "standard__app",
            attributes: {
                appTarget: "TEST_PAGE_2" 
            },
            state: {
                recordIds: recordId
            }
        };

        navService.navigate(pageReference);
    }
})
```